# K-detail-template directive doesn't work when used inside angular template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid, angular-kendo

I am trying to create nested KendoGrid using Angular template but for some weird reason Child Grid is not getting created when used inside Angular Template

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-tmpl">
        <div k-detail-template>
            <kendo-grid options="childOption"></kendo-grid>
        </div>
    </script>
    <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions">
        <span ng-include="'my-tmpl'"></span>
    </kendo-grid>
```

Here is the plunker for the same http://embed.plnkr.co/fLwZrSaNZwLn0RRYanOU/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make it work if you include only the SUB GRID in the template and leave the k-detail-template directive in the main HTML like this:

```
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-tmpl">
            <kendo-grid options="childOption"></kendo-grid>
        </script>
        <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions">
            <div k-detail-template>
                <span ng-include="'my-tmpl'"></span>
            </div>
        </kendo-grid>
      </div>
</div>
```

I tried in your plunker and it works.

Hope it helps (even though is somewhat late)